# Posting a markdown table as Pull Request comment to GitHub using GitHub API

Tags: github, markdown

I am able to post text to a pull request on GitHub using the API

```
https://api.github.com/repos/aftab-hassan/pagerankassignment/pulls/2/comments
```

And using the below as body

```
{
  "body": "Nice change",
  "commit_id": "5dfc67045edc45ed102f6bf6ad0c1209fdd2ef38",
  "path": "README",
  "position": 4
}
```

I am trying to post a markdown table such as below as the body instead of the plain text above.

```
First Header | Second Header
------------ | -------------
Content from cell 1 | Content from cell 2
Content in the first column | Content in the second column
```

However, it gives me an error as follows

```
{
    "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment"
}
```

I did try changing the body type to text instead of json.
I also tried adding `\n`s to the markdown body since it spans multiple lines. However, none of these attempts seem to work, and give me the same error as above.

```
{
  "body": "First Header | Second Header\n
------------ | -------------\n
Content from cell 1 | Content from cell 2\n
Content in the first column | Content in the second column",
  "commit_id": "5dfc67045edc45ed102f6bf6ad0c1209fdd2ef38",
  "path": "README",
  "position": 4
}
```

How can I post a markdown table as comment to a pull request on GitHub via Postman?

Comment: @Waylan I added the JSON body I was using. With this, the JSON becomes valid. However, I still get the response as "Problems parsing JSON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON strings should contain only escaped newlines, not literal ones. So `body` becomes

```
"First Header | Second Header\n------------ | -------------\nContent from cell 1 | Content from cell 2\nContent in the first column | Content in the second column"
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979737/96588) for a more flexible way of dealing with arbitrary input into JSON.