# Unable to correctly use variable in curl command

Tags: xml, bash, curl

I am using a `curl` command and its using quite a lot of variables. And these variables contain XML.

My main XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor ID="_16x6ttxhv1vzbzoop6nddfaece4r9ota2tem7as" entityID="http://jenkins-0.com:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin" validUntil="2038-10-24T23:16:50.279Z" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"><md:Extensions xmlns:alg="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:algsupport"><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#sha384"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#sha224"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha384"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><alg:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/></md:Extensions><md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol"><md:Extensions xmlns:init="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:request-init"><init:RequestInitiator Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:request-init" Location="http://jenkins-0.com:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin"/></md:Extensions><md:KeyDescriptor use="signing"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIC+TCCAeGgAwIBAgIUARYMLNA/4YtY3NmaNBuptIz+NrkwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwFzEVMBMG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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIC+TCCAeGgAwIBAgIUARYMLNA/4YtY3NmaNBuptIz+NrkwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwFzEVMBMG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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat><md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://jenkins-0.com:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin" index="0"/></md:SPSSODescriptor></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

I am doing some post processing i.e. removing new lines and escaping `"`. Im saving the result in a variable called `POST_DATA`

```
POST_DATA=$(cat PRE_DATA.xml | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/\\n/g' | sed 's/"/\\"/g')
```

Now I want to send this XML file as a variable to the `--data` field of my `curl` command.

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://my-end-point \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "metadata": "$DATA",
  "id": "$SP_ID"
}'
```

This clearly did not work as I was not sending the variables correctly.

I tried the following :

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://my-end-point \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d "{
  \"metadata\": \"${DATA}\",
  \"id\": \"${SP_ID}\"
}"
```

I also tried this :

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://my-end-point \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d "$( printf '{ "metadata": "%s", "id": "%s" }' \
           "${DATA}" "${SP_ID}" )"
```

For all the above scenarios, I get:

```
Invalid JSON provided as input.
```

None of these solutions work. However when I use Postman app, it works perfectly fine. Basically I populate `metadata` with the actual value and it works. I replicated the `curl` command with the actual value in the `metadata` field and it works. But when I send that value to a variable and use that variable, it does not work. Ive exhausted all ideas on how to make this work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please include what you mean by "work" in this case - do you get a Bash syntax error, 4xx or 5xx response, or something else?

Comment: Added the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to escape arbitrary text in JSON is to use `jq`. Example session:

```
$ DATA='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <md:EntityDescriptor'
$ SP_ID=1
$ jq --arg metadata "$DATA" --arg id "$SP_ID" '{"metadata": $metadata, "id": $id}' <<< {}
{
  "metadata": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<md:EntityDescriptor",
  "id": "1"
}
```

The `jq` output can then be used in the `curl` command.