# Issue in rendering table in Github comments[EDIT]

Tags: python, github, github-flavored-markdown

So I using a python code to post comment on my PR commits on Github

```
# Create a table
table = f"""
        
| File Changed | Summary |
|--------------|---------|
{"".join(commit_summary)}
"""

# comment body for review comment
comment_body = f"""
{"".join([f"{line}" for line in summary])}

## Files Changed and Summaries

{table}
"""

comment_data = {
        "commit_id": commit_sha,
        "body": comment_body,
        }
comment_url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo_name}/pulls/{pr_number}/reviews'
```

However, on the github comment, the table is coming out as a normal text rather than a nice looking table which I intend to show

Tried asking gpt and check github documentations but I am stuck

EDIT:
For all those asking what the commit_summary variable looks like, it is a list that may have a value like this for example

(f"| {filename} | {summary} |\n")

It has the files changed in the PR and a short summary of what they are and the issues as well

Currently the table I am getting is like this
| File Changed | Summary |
|--------------|---------|
| review_prs.py | The code snippet you provided appears to be

I want it to be something like this

[a properly rendered github comment table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqNJU.png)

Comment: Where does the `commit_summary` variable come from? In order for the markdown to work, it will need to be an iterable in the form `[f"| {file_changed} | {summary} |\n", ...]` for each row in the table.

Comment: Please include an example of what you _want_ the table to look like, versus what the table _actually_ looks like.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Generic function to make a markdown table...

```py
from __future__ import annotations

def build_row(field_widths: dict[str, int], row: dict[str, str]) -> str:
    pipe_escape = '\|'
    inner = '|'.join(f'{row[header].replace("|", pipe_escape).ljust(width)}' for header, width in field_widths.items())
    return f'|{inner}|'

def make_table(headers: list[str], rows: list[dict[str, str]]) -> str:
    field_widths = {}
    for header in headers:
        field_widths[header] = len(header) + header.count('|')

    for row in rows:
        for field_name, value in row.items():
            if field_name not in headers:
                raise ValueError(f"field name {field_name!r} not in headers")
            current_width = field_widths[field_name]
            this_width = len(value) + value.count('|')
            if this_width > current_width:
                field_widths[field_name] = this_width

    header_sep = build_row(field_widths, {h: '-' * field_widths[h] for h in headers})
    header_row = {h:h for h in headers}
    header = build_row(field_widths, header_row)
    table_rows = [build_row(field_widths, row) for row in rows]
    newline = '\n'
    table = f'{header}\n{header_sep}\n{newline.join(table_rows)}'
    return table
```

Then you can use that function to create a table you want with your particular headers and data:

```py
field_names = ['File changed', 'Summary']
rows = [
    {'File changed': '/path/to/foo/bar/baz', 'Summary': '-100 +200'},
    {'File changed': '/path/to/bacon/eggs/spam', 'Summary': '-1 +2'},
    {'File changed': '/path/to/buzz/crash/split', 'Summary': '-1234 +1234'},
]

print(make_table(headers=field_names, rows=rows))
```

Will output:

```
|File changed             |Summary    |
|-------------------------|-----------|
|/path/to/foo/bar/baz     |-100 +200  |
|/path/to/bacon/eggs/spam |-1 +2      |
|/path/to/buzz/crash/split|-1234 +1234|
```

Which when viewed in GitHub markdown, looks like:

[image: GitHub preview UI]

---

When sending the body to the GitHub API, you need to make sure you have it formatted properly. That is: the body of the request needs to be JSON-encoded. If you use the `requests` library, this is done for you when you pass your `comment_data` using the `json` keyword, e.g. `requests.post(comment_url, json=comment_data)` but otherwise you will need to encode your payload correctly.
For more details, see: [Posting a markdown table as Pull Request comment to GitHub using GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52978611/5747944)

Comment: `field_widths[field_name] = max(field_widths[field_name], this_width)` one line and it expresses what you want

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to render the markdown table if i  pass the json as comment_data = {
        "commit_id": commit_sha,
        "body": "First Header | Second Header\n------------ | -------------\nContent from cell 1 | Content from cell 2\nContent in the first column | Content in the second column",
    }

However, i also want to add some text and images along with this table. that is where i am stuck now